# Regarding implementation of PCA

Tags: python

I am implementing PCA in python using sci-kit learn, it's showing error pca not found. Can anyone tell how to solve this problem. Code I have written is below please,check.

Thank you.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from plyfile import PlyData, PlyElement
plt.style.use('ggplot')
reduce_factor = 100
 plyfile = PlyData.read('C:/Users/srinivas/data science with python/DAT210x-master/Module4/Datasets/stanford_armadillo.ply')
armadillo = pd.DataFrame({
'x':plyfile['vertex']['z'][::reduce_factor],  
'y':plyfile['vertex']['x'][::reduce_factor],
'z':plyfile['vertex']['y'][::reduce_factor]`

})

def do_PCA(armadillo, svd_solver):

import numpy as np
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
pca = PCA(n_components=2,svd_solver='svd_solver')
pca.fit(armadillo)

 return armadillo 

%timeit pca = do_PCA(armadillo, 'full')


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_title('Full PCA')
ax.scatter(pca[:,0], pca[:,1], c='blue', marker='.', alpha=0.75)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `pca` only exists in the scope of the `do_PCA` method. If you want to use it outside if that method, you need to pass it out of the method, or create a class and store the values in the state of the object.

Also the `do_PCA` method is never actually called, so it is never even created.